# I want to execute a function like normal but with a string replaced c#

Tags: c#

I have a function that I want to be replaced with a string like so:

```
    string s = "Show";
    MessageBox.s("Hello World!");
```

Is it possible?

Example:

It's like when you do this when programming a console application:

```
    string world = "World!";
    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", world);
```

I just want the "{0}" replaced like this:

```
    string s = "Show";
    MessageBox.{0}("Hello World!"), s;
```

Sorry for the poor explanations!

Comment: Please be more detailed on your problem. As for now it's barely understandable.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Hello {0}!", world));` see: `MessageBox` help and `String.Format()` help on MSDN.

Comment: It's less about what's inside the brackets and more about that I want .Show replaced with a custom string

Comment: The OP wants to call a method whose name is stored in a string...in a Reflection sort of way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
string s = "Show";
typeof(MessageBox)
    .GetMethod(s, new [] { typeof(string) })
    .Invoke(null, new [] { "Hello World!" });
```

Comment: Maybe I went a little wrong by making the example for MessageBox.Show... Will this work for: Form.<StringName>.Text("Something here");

Comment: @Beefy - Basically, yes, but it will require a little tweaking - the `null`, for example, would need to be replaced by the form instance.